# Changing the value of an attribute with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-attribute, spring-bean

There are a number of other questions that deal with this area, but I can't make the solutions there work

I have a transform that splits up a Spring bean file containing multiple beans into a set of files, each with one bean

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/beans/bean" xml:space="preserve"> 
            <xsl:result-document href='{translate(normalize-space(./property[@name="name"])," ", "_")}.xml'
            doctype-public="-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</beans>
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works fine, producing files that start like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans
  PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean class="com.class.mine.Policy" name="bean1">
        <property name="name">
```

In order that the file looks identical to one originally created with just one bean in it (since the file will be checked into source code management, I want only real differences), I want to change the `name="beanN"` attribute to `name="bean0"` in each file. Note that generally the bean tag can contain additional attributes as well as the `class` and `name` ones.

Nothing I've tried based on other answers here works. Mostly, I get errors about "Cannot create an attribute node whose parent is a document node" and "Cannot create an attribute node after creating a child of the containing element".

So I'm missing something obvious. What do I need to add to make this extra change?

Update: the problem seems partly to do with the xml:space="preserve". This is presumably causing text nodes to be created. With that removed, I don't get the errors so often but I still can't get the transform right

(and the output has

```
<beans><bean>
```

How do I get a linefeed between these tags? I can use indent="yes" to get the output formatted, but I really want to preserve the input format as it was originally, making changes only where I have to)

Update: One of my many attempts. This one runs, but is basically an identity transform. result-doc is commented out to make debugging easier for now.  I really don't understand properly how xsl:attribute works so a decent explanation of that might help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="beans/bean"> 
<!--             <xsl:result-document href='{translate(normalize-space(./property[@name="name"])," /", "_+")}.xml'
            doctype-public="-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd"
            omit-xml-declaration="no"> -->
<beans>
<xsl:apply-templates select="bean"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="." /> 
</beans>
<!-- </xsl:result-document> -->
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="bean/@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="name">myvalue</xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Question: Why do you feel you need a linefeed between the tags? Do you think in an XML system that matters in some way?

Comment: It doesn't matter for XML. It does matter because these configurations are to be checked into CVS, and CVS isn't smart enough to know that whitespace differences aren't significant in XML. I don't want extra CVS revisions created for files that are in fact the same - sp I want to end up with the same formatting as would have resulted for less lazy developers who exported the files one by one.

Comment: The answer depends on how exactly you tried to change the attribute value of the bean element. Can you post a snippet of this?

Comment: I can, but as I say, everything's not worked so far so I'm not sure how much the snippet will help!

Comment: Thanks. For the attribute issue, what you've tried is not possible in XSLT, that's why you've got those errors. See @Ians answer for the correct way to do this.

Comment: OK. It's comforting, in a way, to know it was impossible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want specific indentation then you will have to insert the relevant line feeds and spaces yourself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="beans/bean" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bean"> 
    <xsl:result-document href='{translate(normalize-space(./property[@name="name"])," /", "_+")}.xml'
            doctype-public="-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd"
            omit-xml-declaration="no">
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text><!-- newline after the DOCTYPE -->
      <beans>
        <xsl:text>&#10;    </xsl:text><!-- newline and four spaces -->
        <bean>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
          <xsl:attribute name="name">bean0</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
        </bean>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text><!-- newline between </bean> and </beans> -->
      </beans>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the renaming:

```
        <bean>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
          <xsl:attribute name="name">bean0</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
        </bean>
```

first I copy all the attributes (possibly including `name`) off the original `bean` tag, then create a(nother) `name` attribute which will override the one that was copied, then finally copy all the child nodes of the original `bean` element (which includes elements, comments *and* text nodes, so will keep the original indentation).

Comment: Thanks. Looks spot on. I still don't really understand how the copy of the attributes and then the xsl:attribute work - copying (or defining) attributes gets put in the parent node, it seems? But it works!

Comment: aargh. Tried it on a test example, everything worked. Ran it on another example, and all the files have the bean node (and children) on one line :( even though in the source they're on multiple lines/indented. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, panic over, this is a Saxon "feature". I tested with no DTD reference (since I can't work out how to get Saxon to use a proxy when started from Eclipse) but did my later run with the DTD (and off the company VPN) - Saxon helpfully does something different if there is a DTD "By default, if there is a DTD or schema, then ignorable whitespace is stripped from any source document loaded from a StreamSource or SAXSource." Fortunately, this can be changed. (stripWhitespace=none)

Comment: @Paul whether or not a particular bit of whitespace is "ignorable" is something that is defined by the DTD - if you don't have a DTD then by definition there is no "ignorable whitespace".

Comment: Thanks. I just wasn't expecting the presence or not of the DTD to have an effect on whitespace. The Saxon help doesn't suggest it's a DTD feature, suggesting rather it's a Saxon feature. However, now I know about it, no problem

Comment: Ah, foo. I've set the stripWhitespace=none in Eclipse, but it's not having any effect. When I specify a DTD, Saxon's still stripping the spaces. Any ideas?

Comment: use an xml aware application

Comment: @Paul is there a reason why you have to use the (Spring 1.x era) DTD for validation rather than the schema mechanism that's been recommended since spring 2.0?

Comment: @Paul how exactly have you "set the stripWhitespace=none in Eclipse"?  If you're using the javax.xml.transform interface to Saxon then the key you need to pass to `setAttribute` is the URI `http://saxon.sf.net/feature/strip-whitespace`

Comment: @KevinBrown, if I could I would. This is CVS so not an option

Comment: @IanRoberts, for DTD vs schema, really a question for our product team, but backwards and forwards compatbility over 5+ years of different versions is probably part of the answre. On the stripWhite  space, I set it in the Run Configuration /  Transformation Parameters. There's no obvious way to directly pass parameters any other way

Comment: @Paul I don't know what plugin you're using in Eclipse to run your stylesheets, but "transformation parameters" sounds to me like a place to pass in values that the stylesheet will access via top-level `<xsl:param>` elements, rather than a place to configure attributes of the transformer itself.

Comment: @Paul try running it from the command line - download the normal Saxon HE distribution from http://saxon.sf.net and you can run `java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:yourStylesheet.xsl -strip:none inputfile.xml`

Comment: OK, sounds a reasonable explanation. I'll try the command line at some point. Already downloaded Saxon since it's not standard with the Eclipse plugin.